# Add xmlns to root element preserve existing namespaces

Tags: xml, xslt

I have the following XML:

```
<RootNode xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:cac="http://b/2" xmlns:cbc="http://a/2" xmlns:ns0="SomeNamespace" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <cbc:Element1>0000000001234567</cbc:Element1>
   <cbc:Element2>xxxxx</cbc:Element1>
   <cac:Element3>
      <cac:Element4>
         <cac:Element5>
            <cbc:Element6 schemeID="AAA">1234567890123</cbc:Element6>
         </cac:Element5>
      </cac:Element4>
   </cac:Element3>
</RootNode>
```

And I want to add a xmlns attribute to the root node preserving all other namespaces.
I have a XSLT to add the namespace, but it removes all namespaces and add only the xmlns.

**With this XSLT:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="no" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:variable name="vDefaultNS" select="'addedNamespace"/>
    
    <!-- Extra -->
    <xsl:template match="*">
        <xsl:element name="{local-name()}" namespace="{$vDefaultNS}">
        <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**I get:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<RootNode xmlns="addedNamespace">
   <cbc:Element1>0000000001234567</cbc:Element1>
   <cbc:Element2>xxxxx</cbc:Element1>
   <cac:Element3>
      <cac:Element4>
         <cac:Element5>
            <cbc:Element6 schemeID="AAA">1234567890123</cbc:Element6>
         </cac:Element5>
      </cac:Element4>
   </cac:Element3>
</RootNode>
```

**But I want:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<RootNode xmlns="addedNamespace" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:cac="http://b/2" xmlns:cbc="http://a/2" xmlns:ns0="SomeNamespace" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <cbc:Element1>0000000001234567</cbc:Element1>
   <cbc:Element2>xxxxx</cbc:Element1>
   <cac:Element3>
      <cac:Element4>
         <cac:Element5>
            <cbc:Element6 schemeID="AAA">1234567890123</cbc:Element6>
         </cac:Element5>
      </cac:Element4>
   </cac:Element3>
</RootNode>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to add a xmlns attribute to the root node

Actually, you want to move the root element to another namespace. Try:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/RootNode">
    <RootElement xmlns="addedNamespace">
        <xsl:copy-of select="namespace::*"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </RootElement>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Yes, that's it! Thank you.